# Batch Files “Error”

Tags: file, batch-file, batch-processing

Is there any way I can replace the “error” when running batch? I’m using it to delete files older than 5 days and print “files removed” when successful. But now when there aren’t any files to be deleted it prints “ERROR no files found within search criteria” can I replace that with my own text when there aren’t any files to be deleted?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tired, examples of what you expect, examples of whats not happening like you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress errors from coming through most commands by adding ">nul 2>&1". For instance:

```
del *.txt >nul 2>&1
```

To then act on the success or failure of the command, you can use ERRORLEVEL to check the result code of your command:

```
del *.txt >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto fail

Echo Success
Exit

:fail
echo Something went wrong
```